# What is up with Jane Foster in Avengers: Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Thor* and *Thor: The Dark World*, Natalie Portman plays Jane Foster, a physicist whose work brings her into contact with Thor and Asgard.

Jane Foster doesn't get to do a great deal in the *Thor* movies, and doesn't appear (beyond brief references) in any other MCU movies. However, in *Avengers: Endgame*, Foster

> appears once again, apparently played by Natalie Portman, but literally just gets to have a short conversation in a far-off doorway, and get out of bed, totalling less than 10 seconds of screen time.

Are there any out-of-universe comments from anyone involved discussing why the role was so limited?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As I recall Natalie Portman washed her hands of the MCU and didn't want to revisit. What we see of her is probably rehashed from other movies or using doubles.

[**Screenrant**](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/2309881/would-natalie-portman-appear-in-another-marvel-movie-heres-what-she-says)

> The Thor franchise is feeling better than ever before thanks to Thor: Ragnarok, a movie that moves the franchise in a new (and funnier) direction. While the movie is near universally loved, the Thor series has not always been looked at so favorably and it may be telling that it abandons many of the side characters from the previous two movies. One of these characters was Jane Foster, played by Natalie Portman. Portman had something of a falling out with Marvel Studios after Thor: The Dark World and while that experience was not so great for her, she's still open to coming back to the MCU down the road.

Regarding *Endgame*

> However, we don't actually see this scene. The only bit we see of Jane is her waking up and then we spot Rocket hiding behind her bed.
>
> It seems a weird thing to not show (even if the idea of it is a bit icky), and a bit of investigating suggests that **Portman's appearance in Avengers: Endgame consists of previous footage from Thor: The Dark World.**
>
> [**DigitalSpy**](https://www.digitalspy.com/movies/a27252297/avengers-endgame-natalie-portman-jane-foster-cameo/)

Comment: Didn't she appears at the funeral?   Is this also previous footage?

Comment: I don't recall her at the funeral but I've only seen the movie once. But I'm not sure she'd have a reason to be there...as far as I know, she never met Stark.

Comment: @ThePopMachine [This article](https://www.denofgeek.com/us/movies/marvel/280745/avengers-endgame-tony-stark-ending-scene) identifies everyone at Tony's funeral. Jane Foster is not among them.

Comment: she did voiceover, see my answer

Comment: on IMDB, under casts, Portman is archive footage

Comment: I like to think it was actually Keira Knightley as a double...

Answer (score 8):

Paulie_D answered it pretty well but I got something more to add. From [EW.com](https://ew.com/movies/2019/04/26/avengers-endgame-natalie-portman/)

> Anthony explained: “All she did new for this movie was —”
>
> “The voice,” Joe finished.
>
> “A little bit of voice-over when she’s talking in the distance, that’s
>   it,” Anthony added.